# WordPress - Add New Option to Categories

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I have some experience making WordPress plugins, however I am now trying to make a plugin that adds a new field to an existing WordPress function.

Basically, when creating categories, I want to add a field called "alias" where a user can specify an alternate title for a category - so one category might be called "Questions" AND "Q & A".  This new field would have a supporting template tag, so it can be pulled into a template where needed.

Whats the best way to add this functionality into a plugin, so it can be activated and deactivated as needed?

Thanks
Zach

Comment: see this pluggin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-meta/, may not be exactly what you're trying to achive but it can "lead the way"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer on WordPress.Stackexchange: [Adding fields to category edit screen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5955/category-listing-with-thumbnail-and-description-on-home-page/6817#6817).